# Resharper plugin highlighting fails on certain types

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, plugins, resharper

I'm currently trying to extend an existing Resharper plugin which contains some  syntax highlighting for a custom language, and current language keyword highlighting is implemented with a `CSharpDaemonStageBase` that creates a custom `CSharpIncrementalDaemonStageProcessBase`.

Highlighting is achieved by overriding `VisitNode` like so:

```
public override void VisitNode(ITreeNode node, IHighlightingConsumer context) {
    base.VisitNode(node, context);

    DocumentRange highlightingRange = node.GetHighlightingRange();
    string highlightId = ...
    if (highlightId != null)
        context.AddHighlighting(new ICustomAttributeIdHighlighting_Impl(highlightId, highlightingRange));
    }
```

`highlightId` could (in theory) be any pre-defined color in visual studio, and the node should get highlighted according to visual studio options. Unfortunately some of these Id's don't seem to work and result in no highlighting whatsoever.

These are a few of the ones I can confirm are correctly registered with MEF / the resharper plugin (these work properly):

- "HTML Element Name"
- "HTML Attribute Name"
- "HTML Attribute Value"
- "Keyword"
- "Comment"
- "String"
- "Operator"
- "Number"

Those values seem to all produce valid highlighting results, however I'd like to highlight some class/interface reference nodes, and I nothing I can find results in things being highlighted. Some of the variations I've tried and would like to use:

- "User Types"
- "User Types(Interfaces)"
- "User Types - Classes"
- "User Types - Interfaces"
- "class name" (read somewhere that this was the new name for VS2015, still no dice)
- "interface name"

As far as I can tell I should be able to return any string value that maps to a valid color in visual studio, but for some reason none of those work. Someone I know suggested that it might be a problem in VS / MEF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highlight IDs are actually ReSharper highlighter IDs, not Visual Studio text classification IDs - they're not interchangeable. In other words, all attribute IDs used by ReSharper are first registered with ReSharper, using instances of `RegisterHighlighterAttribute`. During installation, these highlighters (with foreground and background colour, etc) are registered with Visual Studio as text classifications, which is how they appear in the Fonts & Colours dialog.

There is an overlap with some highlights, namely "keyword", "string", "number", "comment", "text" and so on - these ReSharper IDs map directly to well known Visual Studio classifications. However, when used in the ReSharper APIs, you're using ReSharper IDs.

For example, the same code is used for Project Rider, the C# IDE based on IntelliJ, that uses ReSharper in the backend. But here, the ReSharper highlight IDs are mapped to IntelliJ attributes for colouring in the IntelliJ editor. Similarly, when showing code in dotPeek, the ReSharper highlight IDs are mapped to the colours defined in the attributes.

You can use existing ReSharper highlights for various identifier types, such as "ReSharper Class Identifier" or "ReSharper Interface Identifier".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Shame I can't automatically match the user's selected coloring.

Comment: You can, by using the ReSharper highlights - "ReSharper Class Identifier", etc.

Comment: Those don't match up - "ReSharper Class Identifier" by default in my installation matches the C++ highlighting scheme, but not C# at all.

Comment: Ah, good point. These identifiers are actually only used if ReSharper's "Colour identifiers" option is enabled in Options &rarr; Code Inspection &rarr; Settings.